# Fixed delete SQL Server database records?

Tags: c#

I use C # to insert records into SQL Server 2005 after inserted me into the table to delete records but not receive an error message, you see the image attached, you do know what software debugging SQL Server on
http://s17.postimg.org/6wjwqdzcf/error_data.jpg

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that there are 7 rows and the data of last 6 rows is same so the error is showing that if you delete this record all the six rows will be deleted. Use a primary key to delete the record.

Comment: tables not use primary keys only a single table, I want to delete 6 rows

Comment: @lamtriendong: ***every*** table ought to have a primary key!

Comment: I think the option to use primary keys, I'm looking for software fixes on you know ?